# Is it okay to use org.eclipse.birt imports in java file?

Tags: birt

I am trying to integrate birt report Engine into my struts2 application, is it okay to have **org.eclipse.birt** imports ? will they create any problems in server side (when i push into main server)?? please elaborate i am new to this!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you are trying to integrate BIRT into your application you can, and will need to, import those packages.

You will need to make sure that the appropriate jars (the one(s)) containing the imported packages) are available to the server at runtime.

Comment: Thanks a ton! Can you suggest me any easiest way to get proper packages imported ?

Comment: If you are developing in Eclipse, just add the BIRT code that you need, then hit ctrl-shift-o to auto import the right classes. If BIRT isn't available to import, you will need to add the jar(s) to Eclipse's build path, or to your configuration file if you are using an external build tool like Ant or Maven.

Comment: I Successfully integrated birt engine with my struts application, but there are around 80 jars and are of 50MB can you please help me in reducing the jars!!!